# Did Nietszche say "all human institutions are intended to prevent mankind from feeling their life"?

Tags: nietzsche

Someone shared this quote with me, saying it's from Nietzsche, but I can't find a source for the translation:

> Is it not the case that all human institutions are intended to prevent mankind from feeling their life, by means of constant dispersion of their thoughts?

I think it might be from page 235 of an English translation of Hadot's Philosophy as a Way of Life.

If that's the case, then it was translated from German to French and then to English, so it's rather indirect.

Comment: It's from the *Untimely meditations /Considerations inactuelles*, in French: "Toutes les institutions humaines ne sont-elles pas destinées à empêcher les hommes de sentir leur vie, grâce à la dispersion constante de leurs pensées ?" and  what's more the site sends you to that book. The original is *Schopenhauer als Erzieher* ( § 4. Erste Veröff. 15/10/1874). but the translation seems to be a very loose paraphrase.

Comment: @sand1. Yeah... I was thinking that the word 'intend', is a bit suspicious - perhaps something lost in translation - unless 'intent' is meant to describe a subconscious kind of motive. Surely no competent philosopher would claim that a conscious motivator - a kind of clear-minded intent - behind all human institutions was the desire to distract us from the emotional experience of life and/or the intellectual examination of it. I can however conceive of this occurring out of some deep-seated, psychological, evolutionary imperative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The answer to the title question is: Yes (kind of)!

Well, I'd translate differently. Actually, the "quote" in that book is a very loose paraphrase:

The original in German from his *Untimely Thoughts*, *Schopenhauer as Educator* (§4) (cheers to @sand1 in comments) reads:

> Sind doch alle Ordnungen des Menschen darauf eingerichtet, daß das Leben in einer fortgesetzten Zerstreuung der Gedanken [p. 318] nicht *gespürt* werde.

My translation would be:

> As all orders of mankind are made so that life, in a continuous distraction of thought, shall not be *felt*.

Note that this is not stated as a question, but an assertion.